# Ruby command line one-liners sub vs. scan

Tags: ruby

How come I can do

```
ruby -pe "sub /.*{((\d+\.){3}).*/, '\115'" < file.txt
```

but if I try `scan` instead of `sub` I get

> -e:1:in `<main>': undefined method`scan' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

This is confusing since `sub` isn't a method on `Object` either.

I also tried it the Perl way, something like

```
ruby -ne "/.*/; puts $1" <file.txt
```

but that didn't fly.

Where can I find the documentation covering this?

Comment: sub is method under kernel which is a module included in the object hence you are getting it under the scope of the main object where as scan isnt if you are running on ruby 2.0. If you are running of 1.8.7 then you call scan by doing $_.scan(pattern)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`sub` is a method on `Kernel`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sub), a module whose instance methods are globally available.  This version of the method operates on the global variable `$_` which [contains the string last read by `gets`](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html).

This is a totally different method than [`String#sub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-sub), which does a similar process but with an explicit string as the receiver, rather than implicit use of `$_`.

Comment: Sounds very convincing but I tried ´Kernel.methods.sort´ and ´Kernel.instance_methods.sort´ and I can't seem to find ´sub´ anywhere.

Comment: I'm also interested in knowing how you got this knowledge and I really hope that the answer isn't 'from reading the source'.

Comment: @JonasElfström what is the version of ruby of ruby you are using ? The kernel module is different in different in different version of ruby as some methods like scan seem to have been deprecated in the latest version of ruby .

Comment: @JonasElfström I knew that "global" methods in ruby are typically declared in one or two places: `Object` and `Kernel`.  You said it wasn't on `Object` so I looked up the docs on `Kernel` and there it was, plain as day.

Comment: @maerics Yes but if one does not know that. What's the way to find out besides asking SO? There ought to be some kind of documentation.

Comment: @AlexWayne Could we agree on the error message being less than perfect then?

Comment: @JonasElfström Well not really.  It's a generic "this method does not exist here" message.  And the `main` object that is the root context of a ruby script, includes the `Kernel` module, injecting those instance methods.  So `undefined method 'scan' for main:Object (NoMethodError)` is perfectly accurate.  The implicit receiver does not have the method you are calling.  What message would you expect?

Comment: @JonasElfström Check the kernel module for ruby 2.0 http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative . We have sub but no scan .Hence that  should clear everything for you :)